# socat: log conversation with serial port

Tags: bash, tty, socat

After some time, I finally got `socat` to behave in the same way as `putty`, using:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS2 115200 cs8 ixoff
socat $(tty),raw,echo=0,escape=0x03,nonblock /dev/ttyS2
stty sane
```

I would also like to log the conversation to a log file.

EDIT:

I figured out a way how to do it, (but I think it's a kludge), so I answered my own question - and it is a valid answer by stack overflow standards.

Comment: `man socat` should give you the way to do that, and here is http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html

Comment: Well, I read [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES) and [this](http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html), as well as the man page. The documentation gave me some ideas to try, but none of them worked: `socat -v log.txt ...` has a header and unnecessary `\r`, while any attempt to pipe first instance of `socat` (the one which binds serial to console) to another (which binds console to a file) either produced an error (too many/few addresses) or an empty file.

Comment: Please post the output of `socat -v log.txt` and what changes need to happen for the file to suit your needs. I'm sure `awk` will do the trick.

Comment: I came here looking for `socat -r FILE` or `socat -R FILE`. The manual page lists what those do. In short, I wanted to log the exact (binary) contents flowing through the serial port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(my first approach was not correct, so I modify)

I have never used `socat`, but <s>if it has `-v log.txt` option I have a possible solution for you</s> as I see with `-v` option it prints the result also to stderr.

I assume You want to have the log file sent into log.txt, cut the first 10 lines and all the `\r` characters removed. On a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) which supports **process substitution** it can be done like this:

```
socat -v ... 2> >(awk 'NR>10 {gsub("\r","");print}'>log.txt)
```

(Mind the space between the two `>` marks!!!)

This will create a process and `>(...)` returns a file like `/dev/fd/68` and redirects the `stderr` to it. Actually this is a pipe to the process specified inside the brackets (`awk`). So the text goes through [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and its output is written into `log.txt`.

As You mentioned, You do not have [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) this can be solved using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (or `tail` and `tr` pipe but it needs an extra process).

```
socat -v ... 2> >(sed -e '1,10 d' -e 's/\r//g' >log.txt)
```

(Mind the space between the two `>` marks!!!)

It seems [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) does not support this, but it worked on a fairly old RedHat Linux.

Actually You can also use `-lf` (I'm not sure that this prints everything You need. Maybe `-v` if a better choice...):

```
-lf <logfile>
    Writes messages to <logfile> [filename] instead of stderr. 
    Some third party libraries, in particular libwrap, might not obey 
    this option.
```

So the original approach also can work:

```
socat -lf >(sed -e '1,10 d' -e 's/\r//g' >log.txt) ...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of creating processes like this. Since I do not have `awk` on that system, I will use `tr` and/or `sed`. But just for testing purposes, I cannot reproduce your command without any translation, i.e. `socat -v ... 2>(cat >log.txt)`

Comment: @Ulrik: Sorry, but I misinterpreted the meaning of `-v`. I thought it needs a file arg and it print to that file, but not. It redirects output also to `stderr`. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Worth noting that you can use the `-x` option to have socat show data in hex format rather than in the more "readable" format provided by `-v`